# running sbt command makes delete key behave wierd

Tags: scala, sbt

- macOS 10.13.3
- SDKMAN 5.6.1+290
- scala 2.14.4
- sbt 1.1.1
- iTerm2 Build 3.1.5
- zsh 5.3 (x86_64-apple-darwin17.0)

Somehow, when starting sbt, 'delete' key does not work as a delete key.  The key makes the cursor proceed (rather than go back) without deleting any characters.

[iTerm2 showing delete key behavior](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M2hDf.png)

I tried the following, but the situation persists.

- Reinstalled sdkman
- Reinstalled scala, sbt
- Removed .zcompdump*
- Created sbt new project
- Removed .ivy2 folder and re-downloaded all scala dependencies
- Used bash instead of zsh

When I tried in a different machine, it did not reproduce. So I can assume that it is due to some configurations or packages that are unique to the problem-making Mac.  But I have no idea what to look for.

Any idea or suggestions?

P.S.
It seems arrow keys do not work as normally should.  Left and right keys do not do anything.  Up and down keys do things people expect.

```
sbt:stream-quickstart-root>asd
```

Then, typing the up key once yields,

```
sbt:stream-quickstart-root>asd   console
```

It looks like showing a command typed previously in the history, but not quite.  The down key enters blank spaces (about five spaces but not sure because cannot go back with left arrow).

Comment: What do you mean by behave weird ? Does everything such as arrow keys work fine ?

Comment: @soichiishida - If this is actually your question that you're trying to edit, can you leave a comment saying so? It's not clear from your edit comment whether you just happen to be experiencing the same issue as user2795530 and are guessing your arrow key issue is also the same or whether you're actually the same person.

Comment: @BSMP sorry.  I have logged in from different physical location, without realizing I posted the question from temporary account.

I commented as follows.

It seems arrow keys do not work as normally should. Left and right keys do not do anything. Up and down keys do things people expect.

 sbt:stream-quickstart-root>asd

Then, typing the up key once yields,

 sbt:stream-quickstart-root>asd   console

It looks like showing a command typed previously in the history, but not quite.

Comment: It's OK, I just wanted to make sure it was you before approving the edit.

Answer (score 1):

The delete key situation sounds like you're having some bad interaction with JLine2, which we use internally. For what it's worth, I personally use iTerm2 with macOS, and it works for me.

1. Do you have TERM set? I think it comes from Preferences > Profile > Terminal > Report terminal type. Mine is `xterm-256color`.
2. Do you have `~/.inputrc` configured? I don't have the file, but I think JLine2 does stuff with keybinding when it finds it.

As a workaround you can try the following:

```
$ sbt -Djline.terminal=unix
```

or

```
$ sbt -Djline.terminal=false
```